# Scrolling two DIVs together in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I want to scroll to DIVs horizontally using scrollbar. I have the following code:

```
 $('#D').on('scroll', function () 
 {
    $('#B').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
  ...
 }
```

It works perfectly on every browser except Internet Explorer and Edge. When I "grab" scrollbar and drag, it works good on IE and Edge too.

But problem begins, when I use arrows on scrollbar or I click somewhere on scrollbar. When I do this, DIV with id="D" scrolls first and then (after 0.4 sec) DIV with id="B" catches up. It doesn't look good at all.

I think IE and Edge scroll DIV first and then trigger event "scroll". But why it works perfectly when I "grab and drag"? Have You got any solution?

[Picture with problem after click on scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGDks.png)

Comment: Can you wrap them both in one `<div>`?

Comment: only solution would be to probably use an interval and watch to see if the position changes.

Comment: @Jackson in current state page it is not possible

Comment: @epascarello like setInterval and set scrollLeft every (let's say) 5ms? I've had done that and i've same problem